# Closed and bounded set $K$ contains a countably infinite set of points $\{x_k\}$ with the property that $d(x_m,x_n)\geq2\alpha>0$. $K$ is not compact

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

$X$ is a complete metric space. Suppose $K$ is a closed and bounded subset with the property that it contains a countably infinite set of points $\{x_k\}$ with the property that $$d(x_m,x_n) \geq 2\alpha >0$$ for all $n\not =m$. Show that $K$ is not compact.

Proof: Let $\epsilon = \alpha>0$ and $B_\epsilon(x_k)$ be open balls of center $x_k$ with radius $\alpha$. Since each $B_\epsilon(x_k)$ contains only one point $x_k$ in $K$, there are countably infinite such open balls. $K=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B_\epsilon(x_k)$, so $K$ is contained in the union of a collection of open subsets of $X$, but $K$ is not contained in the union of finite number of these open subsets.

Is this proof correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not correct.  If you want to show that $K$ is not totally bounded, you need to show that (for some $\epsilon>0$) *there does not exist* any finite collection of elements $a_1,\dots,a_n\in K$ such that $K$ is covered by the balls $B_\epsilon(a_i)$.  So to prove this, you need to start with an arbitrary finite collection of elements $a_1,\dots,a_n\in K$ and prove that the balls $B_\epsilon(a_i)$ cannot cover $K$.  You have done no such thing.

(Also, there is no reason for the equation $K=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B_\alpha(x_k)$ to be true.  But even if it were true, it would not (directly) prove that $K$ is not totally bounded, as you claim.)

Comment: Thank you Eric. I corrected my proof a little bit. I think my proof showed that $K$ is not compact directly instead of showing that $K$ is not totally bounded. Would you mind taking a look?

Comment: Now your proof would be essentially correct if you knew $K=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B_\alpha(x_k)$, but there is no reason for that to be true.

Comment: Right. I understand that. Because $\{x_k\} \subseteq K$, $K=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B_\alpha(x_k)$ may not be true. Wha if I prove there exists a sequence in $\{x_k\}$ which has no Cauchy subsequence?
Given $\epsilon = \alpha>0$ and let $p_1, p_2, ...$ be a sequence of points in  $\{x_k\}$, then for any subsequence $(q_n)$ of $(p_n)$, $(q_n)$ is not a Cauchy sequence since $d(q_m,q_n) \geq 2\alpha >\epsilon$ if $m\not=n$.

Comment: Yeah, that would work!